# How to check if a value already exists in the database with codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I found this line : $this->form_validation->set_rules();
But I have no idea where to use it. it seems complicated and everywhere its mentioned its about 'username' and 'password' fields.
I have a variable called 'utr' which I am POSTing to the same page with ajax submit, now I want to to check if it is a unique value that is submitted on form submit and not already in my database.
The table name is 'orders' and the column name is 'utr'.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check any value which is already exist in database try this code :

utr is the name which is send by form and is_unique validate table.coulmn in database.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'utr', 'UTR Title',
        'required|is_unique[orders.utr]',
        array(
                'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
                'is_unique'     => 'This %s already exists.'
        )
);
```

Comment: Where do I add it ? in the php form post or controller ?

Comment: add this code in controller where validation rule is set

Comment: but there is no validation rule in controller already.

Comment: For more info see Setting Validation Rules in this URL : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: You must need to add the validation rule in controller.

Comment: now after thats done, what do I write inside form post in order to see if its working ?

Comment: Can you share your controller & view form then i can explain.

Comment: they're both too complicated and big. can you maybe come to discord ? you can update the answer here then and i will mark it as answer if we do it correctly.

Comment: yes, please come to discord